# Как использовать GET вместо POST?

Tags: php

Как сделать поиск в базе данных mysql через GET? У меня через POST, как заменить на GET?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM search WHERE title LIKE '%$searchq%' OR url LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("Поиск не может!");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 0) {
        $output = 'Ничего не найдено!';
    } else {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $title= $row['title'];
            $url = $row['url'];
            $id = $row['id'];

            $output .= '<div>'.$title.' '.$url.'</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>

<form action="search.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="search" />
      <input type="submit" value="Поиск" />
</form>
<?php print("$output"); ?>
```

И один вопрос: написал здесь текст `<input type="text" name="search" />`, нажал кнопку `<input type="submit" value="Поиск" />`, и поисковой запрос исчезает, почему? Я думаю, через post... Как сделать url, как яндекс, например `http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=поиск`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Через POST:

```
$searchq = $_POST['search'];
```

Через GET:

```
$searchq = $_GET['search'];
```

Через GET и POST:

```
$searchq = $_REQUEST['search'];
```

Ну и `if(isset($_POST['search']))` поменять.